# VSCode pytest test discovery failed?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest

For some reason, VSCode is not picking up my "test_*" file?

Here is the code:

```
import pytest
import requests
import responses

@responses.activate
def test_simple(api_key: str, url: str):
    """Test"""
    responses.add(responses.GET, url=url+api_key,
                  json={"error": "not found"}, status=404)

    resp = requests.get(url+api_key)

    assert resp.json() == {"error": "not found"}
```

I've tried using CTRL+SHIFT+P and configuring tests, but this also fails, it says: `Test discovery failed` and  `Test discovery error, please check the configuration settings for the tests.`

In my settings, the only thing related to pytest is: `"python.testing.pytestEnabled": true`.

What is going on here? My file starts with "test" and so does my function within that file?